# Read External Storage permission in Android M Error

Tags: android, android-permissions

In onCreate Method

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {


} else {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

In onRequestPermissionsResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[],int[]grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {

        if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        } else {

        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I have tried hard but all ends up with crash application. Permission is not granted to application. Why ? Am I doing any thing wrong? Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the Exception from the log when the crash happens?

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 14436
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this as my code, got from stackoverflow, but forgot who answer it

```
public boolean hasPermission(Context context, String... permissions){
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};
    public void checkAllPermission(){
        if (!hasPermission(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
    }
}
```

try it (modify as your need)

Comment: I had tried this code in simpler form but gives me same error

Comment: ntaloventi Yes.

Comment: can you see in log what is pointing to this error or crash? maybe you could post it?

Comment: I had commented it above. Please take a look. Actully permission is not granted to application

Comment: I figured out the problem. I didnt added permission in manifest file